# does not implement inherited abstract member

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, simplemembership

I wrote a Class in C# about Creating,editing members. In order to write it, i used MembershipProvider but i got error. Here is some of my code:

```
public class SqlMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
public  int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
{
    get { return pMinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters; }
}
private int pMinRequiredPasswordLength;
public int MinRequiredPasswordLength
{
    get { return pMinRequiredPasswordLength; }
}
private string pPasswordStrengthRegularExpression;
public  string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
{
    get { return pPasswordStrengthRegularExpression; }
}

// There is some other functions
}
```

Error:

> 'Expanel.SqlMembershipProvider' does not implement inherited abstract
>   member
>   'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters.get'

In my project, there are lots of errors like this error. What should i do? I tried to write override in class and methods but it didnt work.

Comment: `Ctrl+.` on your class and select something like `implement members ...`

Comment: You can find a sample implementation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: wudzik, it didn't work. Mechanical Object i looked this example, i nearly did exactly what he said. but it still gives an error. i'm confused :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) is abstract. It defines a number of abstract members, which means that when you inherit from `MembershipProvider` you *must* override these members. [`MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.minrequirednonalphanumericcharacters.aspx) is one of these members. So change your code to include the `override` keyword:

```
public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
{
    get { return pMinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters; }
}
```

Comment: Not necessary If he makes `SqlMembershipProvider` as `abstract`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - First you can clearly see in OP's code it is not abstract. Second, there would be almost no point writing an abstract MembershipProvider!

Comment: Yes and "If he" flies to the moon, this also wont work as he'll need supplementary oxygen. There's little point guessing all the things the OP *might* do and instead concentrating on the things s/he has demonstrated to be the case!

Comment: @AliSağırvelioğulları - DONT add further questions as an answer. THIS IS NOT A FORUM. Instead update your question, or more probably ask a new one!